# How to calculate the sum $ x + x^2 +...+ x^n$

Tags: exponential-function, real-numbers, exponential-sum

How can I get the result of this sum:

$$  x + x^2 +...+ x^n $$

Comment: why did you change the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** for any $x \in \Bbb R$ with $x \neq 1$,
$$
1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{n} = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}
$$

Comment: I am not sure the result makes sense for $x=1$. The right side is not defined while the left side is $n$. The right side should be extended as a limit for $x=1$.

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner fixed.  We could also have multiplied both sides by the denominator.

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner: The left side is $n-1$  ;-)

Comment: @Stefan Hamcke Well, $n+1$ to be precise :).